# Autocomplete with javascript, not passing the variables

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using this autocomplete code to be able to pull stock information:

```
var YAHOO = {};
YAHOO.util = {};
YAHOO.util.ScriptNodeDataSource = {};
var stockSymbol;
var compName;

    YUI({
    filter: "raw"
}).use("datasource", "autocomplete", "highlight", function (Y) {
    var oDS, acNode = Y.one("#ac-input");

    oDS = new Y.DataSource.Get({
        source: "http://d.yimg.com/aq/autoc?query=",
        generateRequestCallback: function (id) {
            YAHOO.util.ScriptNodeDataSource.callbacks =
                YUI.Env.DataSource.callbacks[id];
            return "&callback=YAHOO.util.ScriptNodeDataSource.callbacks";
        }
    });
    oDS.plug(Y.Plugin.DataSourceJSONSchema, {
        schema: {
            resultListLocator: "ResultSet.Result",
            resultFields: ["symbol", "name", "exch", "type", "exchDisp"]
        }
    });

    acNode.plug(Y.Plugin.AutoComplete, {
        maxResults: 10,
        resultTextLocator: "symbol",
        resultFormatter: function (query, results) {
            return Y.Array.map(results, function (result) {
                var asset = result.raw,
                    text =  asset.symbol +
                        " " + asset.name +
                        " (" + asset.type +
                        " - " + asset.exchDisp + ")";

                return Y.Highlight.all(text, query);
            });
        },
        requestTemplate:  "{query}&region=US&lang=en-US",
        source: oDS
    });

    acNode.ac.on("select", function (e) {
        alert(e.result.raw.name);
        stockSymbol = e.result.raw.symbol;
        compName = e.result.raw.name;
        alert("stockSymbol is "+stockSymbol);
        alert("compName is "+compName);
    });
});
```

I have a text field where the text is being entered, then I need to display a few pieces of information based on what was entered:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    //$(".selector").button({icons: {primary: "ui-icon-search"}});
    //$(".home").button({icons: {primary: "ui-icon-home"}});
    var q = window.location.href.split("?ac-input=");
    alert("q is "+q)
    if (q && q[1])
        $("input").val(q[1]);
        alert("what is this?" +q[1]);
    runForm();
});
```

..........

```
function runForm(){
    $("#stock_news").html("");
    //var stockSymbol = e.result.raw.symbol;
    alert('stockSymbol in runForm is ' +stockSymbol);
    alert('compname is runForm is '+compName);

    var newsStocks = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?.......";

    $.getJSON(newsStocks, function(data) {
        var headlines = data.query.results.a;
        newStr = "<h3>Current Headlines</h3>";
        newStr += "<ol>";
        for(var i=0; i<headlines.length; ++i){
            var news = headlines[i];        
                newStr += "<li><a href='"+news.href+"'>"+news.content+"</a></li>";
            }
            newStr += "</ol>";
            $("#stock_news").html(newStr);
        });

        htmlStr = '<img src="http://chart.finance.yahoo.com/z?s='+stockSymbol+'&t=5d&q=l&l=off&z=s&region=US&lang=en-EN"/>';
    $("#stock_graph").html(htmlStr);

}
```

What is happening is, the `stockSymbol` and `compName` are correctly set from entering, but for some reason nothing renders on the page, as q is undefined....Any ideas on where I am messing up here?

Figured it out. I needed to call `runForm` inside the `acNode.ac.on("select", function (e)`

Comment: Tip: use `console.log` for debug statements. `alert` steals focus and blocks execution.

Comment: What is the value of `window.location.href`? Also, is `q` `undefined`, `null` or `[]`?

Comment: I can see the merit of developing your own solution, but if you're struggling with implementation why not just use a battle-tested solution for autocomplete like [Typeahead.js](http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/)?

Comment: @FritsvanCampen I am using Eclipse, where console.log print the output? I'm not seeing anything in the console window. Is there a better tool to debug javascript?

Comment: @adamb I didn't develop the autocomplete code, it was written by someone else.

Comment: @user2997527 All the more reason to jump-ship & use a robust, community-proven solution!

Comment: @FritsvanCampen, when I was using alert, it was printing undefined. Then after I would enter the word in the text box and autocomplete had finished running, it would set the variable q correctly, but stockSymbol and compName would be undefined....seems like I am missing the timing of setting these variables maybe

Comment: @adamb, I am not versed well in JS to do this :) The code I'm using is just 2 functions, seemed easy enough for me to do enough damage. :)